# What is the connection between area and rotation?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

For finding a quantity in rotational dynamics, we need a reference point around which we define it. Once, the reference point is chosen, rotational quantities are generally described as the cross product of the vector which connects the reference point to where translational quantity is applied with the translational quantity.

This is a simple enough idea, and somewhat makes sense to me since it makes a consistent model of rotation. However, there is one point which I am never able to understand. The magnitude of the rotational quantity is the area of the parallelogram having sides of the magnitude of translational quantity and vector which connects the reference point to the point where the quantity is applied.

What significance is the fact that this area is equivalent to the magnitude of the amount of rotation? Is there a known deep meaning to this or is it just a fact of life?

Comment: Your intuition is right. One gets a deeper understandig through the notions of even and odd multivectors in differential geometry. A simple, beautiful, and even entertaining starting point is Burke's [*Div, Grad, Curl Are Dead*](http://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/Burke_DivGradCurl.pdf).

You can then move to Burke's textbook *Applied Differential Geometry* (Cambridge 1987).

From there you can also check Bossavit's works, for example *On the geometry of electromagnetism* [available here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254470625_On_the_geometry_of_electromagnetism).

Comment: lmao that sounds like the anti thesis to the book "div grad curl and all that" funny name. I'll check it out

Comment: Please do, it'll change completely your understanding of physics!

Comment: A rough summary is that rotational quantities, or more precisely axial vectors, can more properly be seen as bivectors, which *are* areas, with an inner orientation. They are, so to speak, the 2D generalization of vectors – Burke explains this well. Mathematically they are represented by antisymmetric matrices (hence 3 independent components, which explains why we can alternatively represent them as vectors, triplets of numbers). Such matrices are the generators of rotations, from a group-theoretic point of view. Hence the connection.

Comment: @pglpm after you had said this, I spent a few months on differential forms. If you have time, check out Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry book. It is much more modern and depth than Burke's pdf. I'm sure you would be able to appreciate the contents of the said book :D

Comment: Very happy to hear you delved into the world of differential forms from a geometric point of view! Thank you for the intriguing recommendation, I'll check it out at once :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do $\vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ you are multiplying the magnitude of $\vec{F}$ with the *perpendicular distance* $d$ of the reference point to the line of action of $\vec{F}$.

[image: fig1]

The rule is $$ \| \vec{r} \times \vec{F} \| = (\| \vec{r} \| \cos \theta) \| \vec{F} \| = d \,\| \vec{F} \| $$

And the area of the parallelogram $d\, \| \vec{F} \|$ also uses $d$. This is because the area formula depends on the *height* a triangle, and the height is exactly the perpendicular distance.

So in fact it is a property of the cross product $\times$ that extracts out the perpendicular distance, in a similar fashion as the dot product $\cdot$ returns the parallel distance.